# How to implement multiple users in my to do app (MERNstack)?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, express, mongoose, mern

I am trying to implement multiple users for my to do app, but unsure of the best approach. Basically, I want to allow users to register and login, and only CRUD lists and tasks for their account.

One idea I had was to create a document per user and the data would look like:

```
{
user: "john doe",
password: "qwerty",
_id: ObjectID("1234567890"),
lists:[
   {title: "school",
    tasks: ["math", "english", "science"]
   },
   {title: "work",
    tasks: ["budget", "presentation", "excel"]
   }
]
```

Is there an alternative approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, and from what I can see you listed mongoose as a tag, so I'm assuming you are implementing it. Create a User model:

```
const userSchema = new Schema({
   username: {
      type: String,
      required: true
   },
   password: {
      type: String,
      required: true
   }
})
```

Then you need to figure out if you want to store lists in the document, or if you want to reference them (meaning you put the lists in different documents and attach the id to user).
You will then need to create the user routes, where users can be created, and deleted. you will also want to implement a login. You will then need to create authentication using something like express-jwt and jsonwebtoken where tokens will be sent back and forth from your api and the client. By creating the model and the routes, multiple users can be created.

Comment: thank you. would referencing the lists with a user id or putting the lists in the user's document be better? I know it would matter for my small project but just want to know best practices for these scenarios. much appreciated.

Comment: It really depends. adding lists to the user document is the MongoDB way of doing things, it's also the most efficient since you can get the user and the lists in one query, but it does have some downsides. MongoDB places a size limit on it's documents, so if you want to have lots of lists with lots of data, then relational is the way to go.